# About Gauss hypergeometric function

Tags: functions

I'm not sure, but I think that the function

$_2F_1(-n,-m,;1;x)$

cannot be written through more elementary functions. Am I right? I am asking this as a non-mathematician.

Or in other way: Can above expression be treated as  coefficient of $z^m$ in the product

$$ (1+xz)^n\,(1+z)^m.$$ say? (This has been the one answer on the related question [Binomial series with two binomial coefficents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211025/binomial-series-with-two-binomial-coefficents))

I hope that I do not break any rule with posting like this.....

Comment: Relevant link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2F1%28-n%2C-m%3B1%3Bx%29

Comment: Wj32, thanks a lot. Very useful link. :)