# Summation of products of every third term in two different binomial series?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I need to find the summation of the series given below:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}\binom {n}{3i}\binom {m}{3i}
, \textrm{where} \lfloor n/3 \rfloor =\lfloor m/3 \rfloor 
$$

I know how to find summation of every third binomial and the summation of squares of binomials in a series, but I can't seem to figure out the exact answer of this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider the expression $$f(x)=(1+x)^m(1+x)^n$$ now you've to sum up all the coefficients of $x^k$ where $k\cong0\pmod3$...maybe this will give you a start

Comment: Is the answer? $$ \frac{2^{n+m}+(1+w)^{n+m}+(1+w^{2})^{n+m}}{3} $$

Comment: You can test your proposed answer by evaluating the sum by hand for small values of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Seems like my answer is wrong but i did notice an interesting result where it seems like:$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}\binom {n}{3i}\binom {m}{3i}}{\binom{n+m}{n}},\textrm {where } n=\frac{a+1}{2}\textrm{ and } m=\frac{a-1}{2}$$ converges to 1/3 as a becomes large, which is what i am in need of.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3)$ be the primitive cube root of unity.  Then
$$\frac{1+\omega^k + \omega^{2k}}{3} = \begin{cases}1 &\text{if $3 \mid k$}\\0 &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
So
$$\sum_{k \ge 0} a_{3k} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1+\omega^k + \omega^{2k}}{3} a_k.$$
Taking $a_k = \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}$ yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{3k}\binom{m}{3k}
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1+\omega^k + \omega^{2k}}{3} \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k} 
+ \frac{1}{3}\sum_{k \ge 0} \omega^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k} 
+ \frac{1}{3}\sum_{k \ge 0} \omega^{2k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\binom{n+m}{n} 
+ \frac{1}{3}{}_2 F_1(-m, -n; 1; \omega)
+ \frac{1}{3}{}_2 F_1(-m, -n; 1; \omega^2).
\end{align}
The first term explains the asymptotic behavior you observed.

Comment: what does the F1 function represent here??

Comment: It is the hypergeometric 2F1 function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function  See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211025/binomial-series-with-two-binomial-coefficents

Comment: Doesn't the 2nd and 3rd term just cancel out from what I can see?

Comment: The imaginary parts cancel, but not the real parts.  In fact, the sum of those two is always an integer, but typically not $0$.